# How do I use pipe several times?

Tags: bash, pipe

I tried to do it with function:

```
filter-root () {
echo $1 | perl -pe 's/ /\n/g' | perl -pe 's/.*(emacs|libreoffice|autokey|bkubuntu).*//' | perl -pe 's/^\n//'
}
```

but it doesn't work:

```
$ myList=`git ls-files`
$ filter-root myList
myList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write `bash` variables alone when you assign a value to them:

```
MYLIST=`ls *.txt` # Remember to avoid blanks aroud the "="
```

but if you want `bash` to expand them, you have to add a `$` in front of them:

```
echo $MYLIST # Usually is "safer" to wrap the variable with quotes - echo "$MYLIST"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend a `$` to pass the variable:

```
filter-root $myList
```

Also you should pass as `"$myList"` to prevent that the contents of myList is split into token by Bash ... or you could use `echo "$*"`

Comment: That's true. Something else is also wrong with the way I do it -- it gives different result of the "manual pipe".

Comment: Oh -- I solved it: `filter-root "$myList"`. Thanks to Avio -- actually I have a single string -- so I didn't think quoutes are needed. But it works only this way.